# How to forward request from a servlet in one tomcat to other tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

Is it possible to forward the request from a servlet running to another servlet running in a different tomcat in the same machine? I think its possible to configure this out in a cluster environment but not quite sure how to get this when two tomcat servers are not related in a cluster environment. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can configure a load balancer to redirect the requests based on whatever rules you want.  Here is how to do it: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/balancer-howto.html#Comments

If needed, you can configure each instance of tomcat to run on a different port.